# rails console: How to include a "mixin" and call method from "mixin"

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Why can't I do this:

```
bash$ bundle exec rails console
irb> include CoolModuleIWrote
irb> cool_function_from_module()
```

I'm using rails 5

Comment: Why, you can do that.

Comment: I tried you can't.    include cannot be used in that context

Comment: Nonsense. [It works](https://pastebin.com/x7C7dEGF). Why do you say it can't be used?

Answer (score 0):

To use(call) the methods defined in class or module in your rails app, you need to require the file in console to use that particular class and its methods.

Use the following syntax for requiring the file:

```
require 'file_name'
```

Now it will return true if is not required during the current session of console and then you can use the functionality defined in that particular file.

Hope it answers your question.